# Making the children of a class communicate witch eachtother

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have trouble with the ViewModel of my MVVM pattern-code.

I have a bunch of measurements and a bunch of rules to evaluate the measurements, stored in the classes Rule and Measurement. In my main class MyClass I store my Rules and Measurements then in ObservableCollections (OC) (and connected to a DataGrid).

For all n Rules I create n CollcetionOfEvaluators in one OC and pass the respective rule and all the measurements to each single one.
In each CollectionOfEvaulators I create for the one rule and the m Measurements m Evaluators in an OC.

The Evaluators take the one Rule and the one Measurement and gives back a bool if or if not the respective Measurement passes the respective Rule.

I then have a ListView that displays for each Rule a DataGrid that shows for every Measurement if it passed the Rule.

My problem is to make the Evaluator class to fire the OnPropertyChanged method, if I change the properties of one of the measurements in MyClass. How can I pass the info basically from one child to another child's child? When I play around with the DataGrid of the Evaluators, for example click on the header to rearrange it, it works. So I guess the problem is the c# code not the xaml. So I will leave it out for once. All the bindings are Mode=TwoWay (except the bool, since it has no setter) and  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.

I tried to sketch the problem:
[image]

This is my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;

namespace demo
{
    public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public class Measurement : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private double? myValue1;

            public double? MyValue1
            {
                get { return myValue1; }
                set
                {
                    myValue1 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MyValue1");
                }
            }

            private double? myValue2;

            public double? MyValue2
            {
                get { return myValue2; }
                set
                {
                    myValue2 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MyValue2");
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

        }

        public class EvaluationRule
        {
            public EvaluationRule(double Value1Min, double Value2Min)
            {
                this.Value1Min = Value1Min;
                this.Value2Min = Value2Min;
            }

            public double Value1Min;
            public double Value2Min;

        }

        public class Evaluator : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public Evaluator(Measurement Measurement, EvaluationRule Rule)
            {
                this.Rule = Rule;
                this.Measurement = Measurement;
            }

            public EvaluationRule Rule;

            private Measurement measurement;
            public Measurement Measurement
            {
                get { return measurement; }
                set
                {
                    measurement = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Measurement");
                }
            }

            public bool IsApproved
            {
                get
                {
                    if (measurement.MyValue1 > Rule.Value1Min
                        && measurement.MyValue2 > Rule.Value2Min)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public class CollectionOfEvaluators : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public CollectionOfEvaluators(EvaluationRule Rule, ObservableCollection<Measurement> Measurements)
            {
                this.Rule = Rule;
                this.Measurements = Measurements;

                var Evaluators = new ObservableCollection<Evaluator>();
                foreach (var _measurement in Measurements)
                {
                    var _evaluator = new Evaluator(_measurement, this.Rule);
                    Evaluators.Add(_evaluator);
                }
            }

            public EvaluationRule Rule;

            private ObservableCollection<Measurement> measurements;

            public ObservableCollection<Measurement> Measurements
            {
                get { return measurements; }
                set
                {
                    measurements = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Measurements");
                }
            }

            private ObservableCollection<Evaluator> evaluators;

            public ObservableCollection<Evaluator> Evaluators
            {
                get { return evaluators; }
                set
                {
                    evaluators = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Evaluators");
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Measurement> measurements;

        public ObservableCollection<Measurement> Measurements
        {
            get { return measurements; }
            set
            {
                measurements = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Measurements");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<EvaluationRule> rules;

        public ObservableCollection<EvaluationRule> Rules
        {
            get { return rules; }
            set
            {
                rules = value;
                GetCollection();
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<CollectionOfEvaluators> collection;

        public ObservableCollection<CollectionOfEvaluators> Collection
        {
            get { return collection; }
            set
            {
                collection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
            }
        }

        public void GetCollection()
        {
            var Collection = new ObservableCollection<CollectionOfEvaluators>();
            foreach (var _rule in rules)
            {
                var _collection = new CollectionOfEvaluators(_rule, Measurements);
                Collection.Add(_collection);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must delegate the event. `Evaluator` should listen to the `PropertyChanged` event of its aggregated `Measurement`. The handler of this event can then raise the `Evaluator.PropertyChanged` event in response:

```
public class Evaluator : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Evaluator(Measurement measurement, EvaluationRule rule)
  {
    this.Rule = rule;
    this.Measurement = measurement;

    this.Measurement.PropertyChanged += OnMeasurementPropertyChanged;
  }

  public void OnMeasurementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventAgrs e)
  {
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Measurement));
  }

  private Measurement measurement;
  public Measurement Measurement
  {
    get  => this.measurement
    set
    {
      this.measurement = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Measurement));
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Note that you got a spelling error when naming your class. It's Me**a**surement - you missed an 'a'. Also parameter names should always be lowercase.

Comment: Thanks in general. I don't know why but I keep on misspelling measurement again and again. I was not aware of the parameter convention and will try to adopt it.

Comment: When I type fast I have trained my muscles to mistype display (becomes dispaly) and property (becomes propetry) and change (becomes chnage). Basically only these three words. When muscle memory was trained wrong and keeps fooling you... You should read over [Microsoft Docs: C# Coding Conventions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions). It's always good to follow the conventions of a language, especially when exchanging code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It helps more than you might think. The problem with code conventions is that they differ from language to language. :)

Comment: Nice. I'm glad I could help. Have fun.

Comment: BTW, also thank you for showing me the `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyProperty))` convention over the `OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty")` convention. That seriously improved my life.

Comment: This makes everything easier indeed. No more debugging sessions because of a typo. Renaming properties will never break code again (where we rely on the string representation of a member or class name). `nameof` works with every type or member e.g. methods.

Comment: If you liked it, take it one step further. Take a look at [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netcore-3.1#examples). It makes the argument passing to `OnPropertyChanged` redundant. You can find a brief example  implementation at [Microsoft Docs: INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1#examples)

Comment: Thank's again! I learned about the MVVM pattern from a terrible outdated tutorial, it seems. `CallerMemberNameAttribute` it is then! But I like to also preserve the `OnPropertyChanged()` method. Sometimes I use properties only with `get` for example: I have two int properties A and B and a third property `public int MySum{get{return A+B;}}`. So I call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MySum))` in the setter of A and B. Is this a bad practice?

Comment: No that's fine. But it could be quite confusing or difficult to maintain if a property raises `PropertyChanged` events for other properties. I would add a setter (could be `private`) to `MySum` so that it can raise `PropertyChanged` event by itself: `MySum { get => _mySum; private set {...}}` and then set it explicitly when one of the related properties `A` or `B` changes: `A { get => _a; set {  _a = value; MySum = value + B; }}`. For better readability I would even move `MySum = value + B` to a separate method: `CreateSum() => MySum = A + B` and call it from both setters of `A` and `B`.

Comment: When using `PropertyChanged` I generally wouldn't use computed properties but always raise the `PropertyChanged` event from the modified property's setter.  Also note that when using `CallerMemberName` you can still pass a string to the event invocator. So from inside the `MySum` property setter both `OnPropertyChanged()` and `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MySum))` will work.

Comment: The signature of  `OnPropertyChanged` should be `OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)`. Now, only when the parameter `propertyName` defaults to `null` (or `""`) because no argument was passed, the attribute will automatically resolve the name of the calling member (method or property) and write it to the parameter (in this case `propertyName`).